# getting current quarter earnings when using `request.earnings`

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm trying to use actual earnings from the latest quarterly earnings report in TradingView's pine scripts.

When I use `request.earnings(syminfo.tickerid, earnings.actual)` the series returned does not include the latest quarter.

When I use `request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "EARNINGS_PER_SHARE_DILUTED", "FQ")` or `request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "EARNINGS_PER_SHARE", "FQ")` the returned series contains the latest quarterly earnings.

How can I get the *actual* earnings from the latest quarterly reports? Is there a way to use `request.financial` to retrieve *actual* earnings (opposed to diluted or standard)?

Thanks